# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful for outlook

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

```
final String smtpAuthPassword = "*********";
String emailFrom = "**********";
String emailTo   = "*********888";
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator()
{
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(smtpAuthUserName, smtpAuthPassword);
    }
};
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "outlook.office365.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance( properties, authenticator );
try
{
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFrom));
    InternetAddress[] to = {new InternetAddress(emailTo)};
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    message.setSubject("PLACE_SUBJECT_HERE");
    message.setText("YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE");
    Transport.send(message);
}
catch (MessagingException exception)
{
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am trying to send emails from Java via Microsoft Office email ( Outlook ) using above code. Even though the credentials are correct below exceptions coming up. Can somebody tell me how to fix it?

**javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful**

When i checked the logs, There's a log something like this,
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.office365.com, user=xxxxxr@xxxx.au, password=

Is my PW going as NULL? Something wrong with my code?

Comment: add `session.setDebug(true);` and look what email server responds to you

Comment: Hi even though i have given user credentials in the code, Java code takes the account which i have used it local pc.

Comment: DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=outlook.office365.com, user=****, password=<null>

Comment: and now i am getting javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified? why is that? I have given the password

Comment: The code looks OK, so error message is kinda weird. Did you try another (non-outlook) email account? And what's your MailAPI version? 1.6.0?

Comment: Try to change smtp host to "m.outlook.com"

Comment: Are there any special characters in your password?

Comment: Hi, Nothing helped. Di i have to enable something in my account?>

Comment: were you able to fix it?